# (Fast) eigen decomposition of $DXD$ where $D$ is diagonal, $X$ is symmetric with known eigen decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Assuming that I already know the eigen-decomposition of a real symmetric matrix $X$, is there any way to use it to retrieve efficiently the eigen-decomposition of $DXD$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix? (I mean, more efficiently than computing $DXD$ and decomposing it).

Modulo a base change, this is the same as asking for an efficient way to eigen-decompose $A\Sigma A$ with $\Sigma$ diagonal and $A$ symmetric with known eigen-decomposition.

Maybe some iterative algorithm can use the known eigenvectors as a starting point and converge really fast?

In fact, I strongly doubt there is anything, but I will feel better if someone can provide an definitive argument to close the question.

Comment: On this site questions get closed even without providing a definitive argument ;-)

Comment: well, if $D^2 = I,$ then the decomposition of $DXD = (DU)\Omega (DU)^{-1}, A = U\Omega U^{-1} $

Comment: Have a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1929763/88146

Answer (score 0):

The thing  you care about is $DXD$. Let's rename that $A$. And let's say $U$ is the eigen-vector matrix of $X$ and $V$ is the eigen-value matrix of $X$.

$$
\begin{align}
A &= DXD\\
&= DU'VUD\\
&= D'U'VUD\\
&= (UD)'V(UD)
\end{align}
$$

I would say this is the eigen-decomposition of $A$.  $UE$ is the eigen-vector matrix and $V$ is the eigen-value matrix.