# Eigen decompose a symmetric block matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I have two matrices A and Z.

A is a symmetric $t$-by-$t$ matrix with ones along the diagonal:

$$
A=
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & c_{1,1} & \cdots & c_{t,1}\\
c_{1,1} & 1 & \cdots & c_{t,2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_{t,1} & c_{t,2} & \cdots & 1
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Z is an "indicator matrix".  What I mean by this is that it is an $n$-by-$t$ matrix with exactly $n$ entries that are $1$, and all the rest of the entries are $0$.  There is exactly one $1$ per row:

$$
Z=
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

This type of matrix is common in statistics because it maps observations (there are $n$ of them) to groups (there are $t$ groups).

I need to compute the eigen vectors of $ZAZ^T$.  I'm sure it's of the same rank as $A$, but somehow R (the programming language I use) still gives me back something.  In cases where $n >> t$ (most of the cases I'm interested in), it takes a lot longer to compute the eigen vectors of $ZAZ^T$ than to compute the eigen vectors of $A$.

Is there any way to "post-process" the eigen vectors of $A$ to give the eigen vectors of $ZAZ^T$?

Comment: Its rank is at most the rank of $A$. It will have lesser rank if $Z$ has any zero columns, i.e., if not all groups are represented in the observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$B=ZAZ^{T}$

Find the eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition of $A$,

$A=UDU^{T}$.

Then

$B=ZUDU^{T}Z^{T}=(ZU)D(ZU)^{T}$

You've now diagonalized $B=ZAZ^{T}$. The columns of $ZU$ are eigenvectors of $B$ (corresponding to $B$'s nonzero eigenvalues.)

Note that because $Z$ isn't a unitary transformation, this screws up the scaling of the eigenvalues.  You can easily work out that the eigenvalues of $A$ have been scaled (by the number of ones in each column of $Z$.)

Comment: Very clear explanation and clearly correct.